# Is @JsonTypeResolver the only option for resolving using multiple properties?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have incoming JSON data in the following format

```
{
    "header": {
        "schema_id": {
            "namespace": "omh",
            "name": "physical-activity",
        },
    },
    "body": {
        "activity_name": "walking",
        "distance": {
            "value": 1.5,
            "unit": "mi"
        },
    }
}
```

and corresponding Java classes that looks like

```
public class DataPoint<T extends Measure> {

    private DataPointHeader header;
    private T body;
```

and

```
@JsonNaming(LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
public class PhysicalActivity extends Measure {

    private String activityName;
    private LengthUnitValue distance;
```

I'd like Jackson to resolve `body` to the `PhysicalActivity` type based on the `schema_id` in the JSON document, e.g. in pseudocode

```
if schema_id.namespace == 'omh' && schema_id.name == 'physical-activity'
     then return PhysicalActivity.class
```

I've tried doing this with `@JsonTypeIdResolver` but if I try to navigate to `header.schema_id.name` with `@JsonTypeInfo`, e.g.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
        property = "header.schema_id.name")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(DataPointTypeIdResolver.class)
public abstract class Measure {
```

I get a `missing property: 'header.schema_id.name'` error. And even if I could, I don't think I can take a decision on both the `namespace` and `name` properties.

Is there a sane way to do this besides building from scratch with `@JsonTypeResolver`?

Answer (score 2):

In the Jackson source there seem to be lots of assumptions that type ids are strings, so I suspect that JsonTypeResolver is a way to go... It certainly didn't seem straightforward though!

At least for when you have just 'header' and 'body' properties, a full-custom deserializer isn't too hard:

```
public static class DataPointDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DataPoint<?>> implements ResolvableDeserializer {
    private JsonDeserializer<Object> headerDeserializer;
    private Map<SchemaId, JsonDeserializer<Object>> activityDeserializers;

    public DataPointDeserializer() {
        super(DataPoint.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        headerDeserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructType(
                DataPointHeader.class));
        activityDeserializers = new HashMap<>();
        activityDeserializers.put(new SchemaId("omh", "physical-activity"),
                ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructType(PhysicalActivity.class)));
    }

    @Override
    public DataPoint<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        String fieldName = p.nextFieldName();
        if (fieldName == null)
            throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(p, JsonToken.FIELD_NAME, "expected 'header' and 'body' fields");
        if (fieldName.equals("header")) {
            p.nextToken();
            DataPointHeader header = (DataPointHeader) headerDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
            JsonDeserializer<Object> bodyDeserializer = activityDeserializers.get(header.schemaId);
            if (bodyDeserializer == null) throw ctxt.mappingException("No mapping for schema: " + header.schemaId);
            fieldName = p.nextFieldName();
            if (fieldName == null)
                throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(p, JsonToken.FIELD_NAME, "expected 'body' field after header");
            p.nextToken();
            Measure body = (Measure) bodyDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
            DataPoint<Measure> dataPoint = new DataPoint<>();
            dataPoint.header = header;
            dataPoint.body = body;
            return dataPoint;
        }
        else if (fieldName.equals("body")) {
            p.nextToken();
            try (TokenBuffer tb = new TokenBuffer(p)) {
                tb.copyCurrentStructure(p);
                fieldName = p.nextFieldName();
                if (fieldName == null)
                    throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(p, JsonToken.FIELD_NAME, "expected 'header' field after body");
                if (!fieldName.equals("header"))
                    throw ctxt.weirdStringException(fieldName, DataPoint.class, "Unexpected field name");
                p.nextToken();
                DataPointHeader header = (DataPointHeader) headerDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
                JsonDeserializer<Object> bodyDeserializer = activityDeserializers.get(header.schemaId);
                if (bodyDeserializer == null)
                    throw ctxt.mappingException("No mapping for schema: " + header.schemaId);
                JsonParser bodyParser = tb.asParser();
                bodyParser.nextToken();
                Measure body = (Measure) bodyDeserializer.deserialize(bodyParser, ctxt);
                DataPoint<Measure> dataPoint = new DataPoint<>();
                dataPoint.header = header;
                dataPoint.body = body;
                return dataPoint;
            }
        }
        else throw ctxt.weirdStringException(fieldName, DataPoint.class, "Unexpected field name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go through that carefully and post feedback.

Comment: I've just realised it doesn't check for and consume the end-object after the fields, I only tested it on standalone documents

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to use path expressions for matching properties. This would require access to the full JSON (sub-tree).

With Jackson 2.5, there is slight relaxation from requirement for type ids to be scalar values (usually Strings), so that [JSOG](https://github.com/jsog/jsog) may be supported. More background is on this issue:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/622

But I don't think that is far enough to let you use standard Jackson type id resolution.

One thing you might consider are Creator methods, something like:

```
abstract class Measure {
   // either constructor, or static method:
   @JsonCreator
   public static Measure construct(
     @JsonProperty("header") HeadOb header, // or JsonNode, Map etc
     @JsonProperty("body") JsonNode body) {
        // extract type info, build actual instance from body
     }
}
```

or, perhaps `Converter` where you use an intermediate wrapper to header bound, and body only bound to `JsonNode` or `Map`, and then construct from there.